# Using Ember.js for Single Page Website (not really a web app)

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I just want to try using Ember.js for a website I am doing (**Disclaimer:** I am a Java web developer, GWT).

So far what I have tried is to slap the whole body tag code into like this

```
<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars"> 
      <!-- The whole page -->
  </script>
</body>
```

Now, I just want to take advantage of Ember.js stuff like components, models and validation for my website.

Here's a run down of the dependencies involved:

```
   <script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.lazyload/1.9.1/jquery.lazyload.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
   <script src="js/main.js"></script>

   <!-- Ember -->
   <script src="js/libs/handlebars-v3.0.0.js"></script>
   <script src="js/libs/ember-template-compiler-1.10.0.js"></script>
   <script src="js/libs/ember-1.10.0.debug.js"></script>
   <script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

**app.js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {

});
```

The thing is, when I put the body into a x-handlebars script the jQuery plugins (like bxslider, carousel, etc.) that used to work would not work with the stuff that was inside the script tag.

**What could be wrong with my approach?**

Comment: Use JQuery plugins inside `view` or `component`'s `didInsertElement`. You can try [Exyht-A Blogging App](https://github.com/Exyht/exyht) to get a basic idea of an Ember App.

Comment: I suggest you watch the following by evil trout... http://eviltrout.com/2014/06/03/jquery-component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is rendered in your `<script type="text/x-handlebars">Script</script>` is being rendered after your JQuery code has run. You can fix this by modifying using the `didInsertElement` event in your `view` or `component` to run any code that is needed to initialize the elements in the view that was rendered.

```
didInsertElement: function() {
    this.$().DoStuff();
}
```

There are a number of other questions on StackOverflow - including, for instance, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28415037/77074) - addressing similar issues, so you should be able to adapt their approaches.